# Cannot upload an image on imgur [API 3]

Tags: php, curl, image-uploading, imgur

I'm trying to upload images on imgur but I often have problem and I am not able to upload the image.

In the code I'll publish I don't understand why I keep getting the boolean value: `false` as result of `curl_exec($ch);` and **not** a json string. From the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) it means that the post failed but I don't understand why.

Here I successfully read the image from a post request

```
$imageContent = file_get_contents($myFile["tmp_name"][$i]);
if ($imageContent === false) {
    // Empty image - I never get this error
} else {
    //Image correctly read
    $url = $this->uploadLogged($imageContent);
}
```

While here is my attempt to upload it

```
public function uploadLogged($image){
    $upload_route = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_route);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer '.$this->access_token));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => base64_encode($image)));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $responseDecoded = json_decode($response);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $link = $responseDecoded->data->link;
    if( empty($link) ){
        throw new Exception("Cannot upload the image.<br>Response: ".json_encode($response));
    }
    return $link;
}
```

Moreover `$this->access_token` correspond to a **valid** access token

Comment: Your code yields a json string as response from imgur (albeit an authentication failed message as i have no access token). Where do you get 'false' ?

Comment: @FreudChicken Nope, as response from imgur I get the boolean value false, not a json string. From the php manual it means that the curl failed but I don't understand why: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: Not in my test bed: i cut&paste your code and print out the $result string. Check also the answer bellow

Comment: I see, from the answer below seems that the image is not read correctly. How are you passing the image to the function?

Comment: That's beside the point: the curl function is set up correctly as far as http is concerned, which was your question really.

Comment: @FreudChicken The question is why I am getting false and I cannot upload the Image. If the http request is correct so the problem is not the code but the server provider?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169650/discussion-between-freud-chicken-and-timmy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when curl_exec returns bool(false), there was an error during the transfer. to get an extended error description, use the curl_errno() and curl_error() functions. to get even more detailed info of the transfer, use the CURLOPT_VERBOSE and CURLOPT_STDERR options of curl_setopt. eg

```
$curlstderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$curlstderrh));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$curlstderr=file_get_contents(stream_get_meta_data($curlstderrh)['uri']);
fclose($curlstderrh);
if(false===$response){
   throw new \RuntimeException("curl_exec failed: ".curl_errno($ch).": ".curl_error($ch).". verbose log: $curlstderr");
}
unset($curlstderrh,$curlstderr);
```

should get you both the [libcurl error code](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html), an error description, and a detailed log of what happened up until the error, in the exception message.

common issues include an SSL/TLS encryption/decryption error, timeout errors, and an unstable connection.

Comment: Thanks to your code I get this: `[Error code: 52] - Empty reply from server` is it possible to solve or is a problem of imgur?

Comment: @Timmy can you post the CURLOPT_VERBOSE log?

Comment: (Un)fortunately today seems to be working nice so very probably it was a server problem. Thank you for your help

Comment: I obtained again the error, this is what I obtain: `Error: curl_exec failed: 52: Empty reply from server. verbose log: ` The log seems to be empty

Comment: @Timmy hmm, instead of stream_get_contents, try `$curlstderr=file_get_contents(stream_get_meta_data($curlstderrh)['uri']);` , still empty?

Comment: Ok, i'll try in this other way, when I have a new error I'll post here the output

Comment: Nothing changed: `File: /membri/.dummy/temp/phpRhQKPT - Error: curl_exec failed: 52: Empty reply from server. verbose log: `

Comment: @Timmy the stream_get_contents code was affected by this bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 .. but no idea why the file_get_contents code failed